# Jquery ajax call response JSON format

Tags: json

I have a Jquery ajax call which is returning the following supposedly JSON format?
I would like to know if this is really a JSON format

```
{"rows":["0","Success - Programming Initiated"]}
```

I thought the JSON format is like this below

```
{"rows":["status_code":"0", "status_desc" : "Success - Programming Initiated"]}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. You have object with field _rows_ and this field contains array of elements.

Comment: It may not be the (also legal) JSON you expected, but it is legal JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to verify it is

1. Open your chrome, click right and click the Inspect element
2. open the console and assign your json to a variable

like this

```
var test={"rows":["status_code":"0", "status_desc" : "Success - Programming     Initiated"]}
```

when chrome throws error, it means that your json is incorrect.

Notice that json is combined with **Array** and **Object**,but

```
["status_code":"0", "status_desc" : "Success - Programming Initiated"]
```

is neither an Array nor an Object, So it's incorrect.it should be

```
{"rows" :{"status_code":"0", "status_desc" : "Success - Programming Initiated"}}
```